# Temporarily stop redirection to get user input

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a script that uses a pretty standard method for capturing everything to a log file:

```
exec 6>&1 1>"$logFile" 2>"$logFile"

# do stuff

exec 1>&6 2>&6 6>&-
```

Now, I want to capture some user input, but I can't seem to get the user data returned from the function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function getInput() {
    local userInput
    # disable redirection temporarily
    exec 1>&6 2>&6 6>&- 
    read -rp "Prompt: " userInput
    # restore redirection
    exec 6>&1 1>>"$logFile" 2>>"$logFile"
    echo "$userInput"
}

logFile="$HOME/foo.txt"

# enable redirection to the log file
exec 6>&1 1>"$logFile" 2>"$logFile"

input=$(getInput)

exec 1>&6 2>&6 6>&-

echo "Got $input"
```

The prompt shows up and I can enter a response, but the input isn't returned to the main script. Why?

---

Editing to add that if I remove the `exec` lines from the function, the input is read and returned correctly, but of course the prompt to the user is not displayed, even if I do this redirection: `read -rp "Prompt: " input >&6`

Comment: Input comes from FD 0, which isn't involved in any of the redirection.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm confused!

Comment: Try using different variables in the function and main program, rather than `input` for both.

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but the redirection should use `2>&1` rather than repeating `>"$logfile"`

Comment: In the script proper, the variables have different names, and the one in the function is declared `local`. Will update my PoC code in the question to reflect this.

Comment: The prompt in `read -p` is written to stderr, not stdout, so use `read -rp "Prompt: " input 2>&6`

Comment: That does work, and is much easier than redoing all that `exec` stuff every time. I'm still curious why my original script didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the function is redirecting output to the log file before it does `echo "$userInput"`. But command substitution works by running the command with its output redirected to a pipe, and you're overriding this. As a result, the nput is being written to the file, not the pipe.

You need to save the output redirection and then restore to that saved value, rather than hard-coding the log file into the function.

I've also modified your script to save and restore `stdout` and `stderr` separately, rather than assuming they're initially pointing to the same thing. Also, since `read -p` uses `stderr`, I only save/restore that FD in the function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function getInput() {
    local userInput
    # disable redirection temporarily
    exec 8>&2 2>&7
    read -rp "Prompt: " userInput
    # restore redirection
    exec 2>&8 8>&-
    echo "$userInput"
}

logFile="$HOME/foo.txt"

# enable redirection to the log file
exec 6>&1 7>&2 1>"$logFile" 2>&1

input=$(getInput)

exec 1>&6 2>&7 6>&- 7>&-

echo "Got $input"
```

But all of this redirecting is really unnecessary, you can just redirect the `read` command:

```
read -rp "Prompt: " userInput 2>&7
```

Note that it should be `stderr` that gets redirected here, not `stdout`; `read -p` uses `stderr` precisely so that it can be used when `stdout` is redirected (it's less common to redirect `stderr` in such cases).

Comment: Marked accepted but I'll just end up using your comment on how to properly redirect the `read` command!

Comment: I've added that to the answer for completeness.